# Why is peak of the signal taken as the Time Delay

Tags: signal-analysis, cross-correlation, peak-detection

I was reading this research paper titled 'The generalized Correlation Method for Estimation of Time Delay' by C. Knapp and G.C. Carter. They develop an ML estimator and in the introduction mention that 'The time shift causing the peak is an estimate of the true delay D'.

I did not understand why specifically the peak of the signal was chosen? Can the start of the signal be chosen instead ? What would be the difference between the two in general when any signal is considered?

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what the OP believes or thinks, the *peak* (a.k.a. global maximum) of the *signal* (or the *location* of the peak for that matter) is **not** what is what is being used as the Time Delay.

We have two signals which are actually two copies of the *same* signal except that one copy is delayed with respect to the other. If one copy is denoted $s(t)$, then the other copy is $s(t-\tau)$ where $\tau$ is the delay between them. In particular, if $s(t)$ "starts" at $t=0$, then $s(t-\tau)$ "starts" at $t=\tau$.  If the global maximum of $s(t)$ occurs at $t=\hat{\tau}$, then the global maximum of $s(t-\tau)$ occurs at $t=\tau+\hat{\tau}$, and so on.

We wish to determine the value of $\tau$. Once we know the value of $\tau$, everything else falls in place; the signal $s(t-\tau)$ "starts" $\tau$ seconds after $s(t)$ starts, and the global maximum of $s(t-\tau)$ occurs $\tau$ seconds after the global maximum of $s(t)$ etc. What is suggested as a means of determining the value of $\tau$ is a *correlation method*: find the cross-correlation *function* between $s(t)$ and $s(t-\tau)$ and determine *where* the peak of this cross-correlation *function* is.  The *location* of the *peak* of the **cross-correlation function** is an estimate of the value of time delay $\tau$ between $s(t)$ and $s(t-\tau)$.

So, why does all this work? Well, the cross-correlation function $R_{x,y}(\lambda)$ of any two signals $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ is defined by
$$R_{x,y}(\lambda) = \langle x(t), y(t+\lambda)\rangle$$
and as a special case, the *autocorrelation* function $R_x(\lambda)$ of $x(t)$ is defined as the cross-correlation function of $x(t)$ with itself: $$R_x(\lambda) = R_{x,x}(\lambda) = \langle x(t), x(t+\lambda)\rangle$$
which is well-known to have a peak at the origin: $R_x(0) \geq |R_x(\lambda)|$ for all $\lambda$.
Thus, $$R_{s(t), s(t-\tau)}(\lambda) = \langle s(t), s(t-\tau+\lambda)\rangle = R_s(\lambda-\tau)$$ and we see that the maximum value of the cross-correlation function $R_{s(t), s(t-\tau)}(\lambda)$ has a maximum when $\lambda = \tau$.  That is, if we compute the *cross-correlation* function $R_{s(t), s(t-\tau)}(\lambda)$ and *locate* its peak. value, the *location* of the peak tells us the value of $\tau$, the *delay* of $s(t-\tau)$ with respect to $s(t)$.

Comment: So only because the autocorelation function has a peak in the beginning, a peak to peak comparison is made? Otherwise for example if I am analysing an impact event, does it matter if I choose the time instance where the signal starts rising vs the signal peak ? How can I compare them both?